# Symfony 2.8.x: Custom FormType overwrites form variables

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form with multiple fields. 
I also use some custom form-types, for example a DivType to add text, buttons, pictures or other stuff, not mapped to the database.

Upgrading the code to the Symfony 2.8 syntax results in undisired behavour.

My form:

```
class ExampleType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        // A couple of fields, for example field1
        $builder->add('field1', 'text', array(
            //  text field
        ));

        // A div element
        $builder->add('div_id_1', new DivType(), array(
            'content' => 'Just some content in the first div',
        ));

        // Another div
        $builder->add('div_id_2', new DivType(), array(
            'content' => 'A div with some images, buttons or other cool stuff',
        ));

    }
}
```

My DivType.php:

```
class DivType extends AbstractType {

    private $content;
    private $id;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $this->content = $options['content'];
        $this->id = $builder->getName();
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) {
        $view->vars['div_content'] = $this->content;
        $view->vars['div_id'] = $this->id;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array (
            'mapped' => false,
            'content' => false,
        ));
        $resolver->setDefined(array('div_id'));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'div';
    }
    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'div';
    }

}
```

My template code:

```
{% block div_row %}
    <div id="{{ div_id }}">
    {% if div_content is defined and div_content %}
        {{ div_content }}
    {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Result of the div's (so far it is working OK :-):

```
...
<div id="div_id_1">
    Just some content in the first div
</div>
<div id="div_id_2">
    A div with some images, buttons or other cool stuff
</div>
...
```

Now I am upgrading to symfony 2.8:
In the deprecation messages in the profiler this line shows up:
"Passing type instances to FormBuilder::add(), Form::add() or the FormFactory is deprecated since version 2.8 and will not be supported in 3.0. Use the fully-qualified type class name instead (MyBundle\Form\Type\DivType)"

So I changed the syntax in my ExampleType class to the new syntax (DivType::class):

```
$builder->add('div_id_1', DivType::class, array(
    'content' => 'Just some content in the first div',
));
$builder->add('div_id_2', DivType::class, array(
    'content' => 'A div with some images, buttons or other cool stuff',
));
```

Now the result is not what I was expecting. 
I get the number of div's added to the form, but all are overwritten by the values of the last added element, which obviously is not very usefull...

```
<div id="div_id_2">
    A div with some images, buttons or other cool stuff
</div>
<div id="div_id_2">
    A div with some images, buttons or other cool stuff
</div>
```

Does somebody have a clue what I'm doing wrong?
Or is there an alternative approach I can use to add custom formtypes?

Comment: I suspect the problem might be in getName which is also depreciated in 2.8 and going away in 3.0.  Try using getBlockPrefix instead though I'm not sure if that will give you an individual div_id or not.

Comment: It doen't matter if the getName() function exists. I got the same result, the values are overwritten. In the FormTypes avaliable in symfony they use "return $this->getBlockPrefix();" for backward compatiblity. Trying this gives me the same result.

Comment: Your code sets the id with: $this->id = $builder->getName(); I was a bit surprised that it seems to work in 2.7.  Or maybe the unique id is actually being set someplace else?  I suppose you could try setting it via the options array.

Comment: Thanks, My actual code to pass the id (or other variables) is:   if (array_key_exists('div_id', $options)) { $this->id = $options['div_id']; } else { $this->id = $builder->getName(); } Doesn't make a difference: all the variables are overwritten. The code above was the minimum to explain the problem.

Comment: I have not dug into the 2.8/3.0 form code but I suspect that the same DivType instance is now being used for both form fields so storing the content as instance data is not going to work.  Try pulling it from your options array in buildView and see what happens.

Comment: Please consider posting your new code as an answer.  Other people might run across this rather unexpected behavioral change.  Be good to have a reference answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Cerad, I was able to solve the problem!
Apparently I had made it too complicated... using the $options in buildView method and removing them from the buildForm method did do the job.

My new DivType:

```
class DivType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) {
        $view->vars['div_content'] = $options['content'];
        $view->vars['div_id'] = $options['div_id'];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array (
            'mapped' => false,
            'content' => false,
        ));
        $resolver->setDefined(array('div_id'));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'div';
    }

}
```

Maybe a better and more cleaner way is to use the element-id directly in twig,  using the variable 'form.vars.name' for the id, instead of adding the extra variable 'div_id':

```
<div id="{{ form.vars.name }}">
```